# iframe responsive video not works in mobile

Tags: video, iframe, bootstrap-4

Good morning to all. I've a question about  tag. I'm working on a website made with bootstrap 4.3.1 and I need to insert some responsive videos, but I've tested video load on desktop and iPad devices, but in mobile not works and it show me like as a "broken frame". I post below a code of video and image that appears on mobile[image: iframe_broken]. Someone knows why it happens?

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.lottici-graficstudio.com/prove/Eqc20_2019_WEB.mp4" frameborder="0"  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: what phone, system and browser you are using to test your `<iframe>`?It could be a cross platform issue without knowing those information.

Comment: Hi! I'm using Chrome browser in Android Samsung phone.

Comment: Why don't you use the video element? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Because I followed Bootstrap 4.3.1 code for embedding video. I'll try your your suggestion and then I'll update you if it works or not :)